# KafkLog4JAppender not pushing application logs to kafka topic

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka

I am pretty new to using the Kafka stream.
In a particular requirement I have to push my log4j logs directly to Kafka topic.

I have a standalone kafka installation running on centos and i have verified it with the kafka publisher and consumer clients. Also i am using the bundled zookeeper instance.

Now i have also created a standalone java app with log4j logging enabled. Also i have edited the log4j.properties file as below -

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/edureka/Desktop/Anurag/logMe
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}{UTC} %p %C %m%n

log4j.logger.com=INFO,file,KAFKA

#Kafka Appender
log4j.appender.KAFKA=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}{UTC} %p  %C %m%n

log4j.appender.KAFKA.ProducerType=async
log4j.appender.KAFKA.BrokerList=localhost:2181
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Topic=test
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Serializer=kafka.test.AppenderStringSerializer
```

Now when i am running the application, all the logs are going into the local log file but the consumer is still not showing any entry happening.
The topic i am using is test in either scenario.

Also no error log is being generated the the detailed logs of the log4j library are as below -

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a1d92a.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a1d92a class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a1d92a.
log4j: Using URL [file:/home/edureka/workspace/TestKafkaLog4J/bin/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/home/edureka/workspace/TestKafkaLog4J/bin/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[DEBUG, stdout, file].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "file".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "file".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "file".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [/home/edureka/Desktop/Anurag/logMe].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [5MB].
log4j: setFile called: /home/edureka/Desktop/Anurag/logMe, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "file" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
2015-05-11 19:44:40 DEBUG TestMe:19 - This is debug : anurag
2015-05-11 19:44:40 INFO  TestMe:23 - This is info : anurag
2015-05-11 19:44:40 WARN  TestMe:26 - This is warn : anurag
2015-05-11 19:44:40 ERROR TestMe:27 - This is error : anurag
2015-05-11 19:44:40 FATAL TestMe:28 - This is fatal : anurag
2015-05-11 19:44:40 INFO  TestMe:29 - message from log4j appender
```

Any help will be really great.
Thanks,
AJ

Comment: Any help guys, sorry for such a quick follow up. its a bit urgent :)

Answer (score 1):

In your output, I don't see the KAFKA appender being created, so no wonder nothing is logged to Kafka. I'm guessing the reason for that is that you only log from a class named TestMe (probably in the default package), while the KAFKA appender is only added to the logger named "com".

Comment: okay, i got my error, i had two copies of log4j.properties and i was updating the wrong one. Anyways your answer made me relook at that. But now i am hitting something like below -


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.liftedTree1$1(Unknown Source)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a Scala version issue (you might have Scala 2.11 on the classpath and using the Kafka lib for Scala 2.10, or something along these lines).